# Problem with implementing 2 layer Neural Network using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I tried creating a neural network with 2 layers using numpy only. My algorithm outputs the same value for all the Y's
What is my mistake?

[text](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b1Qd1oSi-eBVT8swveNTvFwIUeEEVYSkhLQMhDkvUvU/edit?usp=sharing)
Here is dataset i used

First layer has 2 neurons with sigmoid activation and the output layer has 1 neuron with sigmoid activation

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sigmoid(z):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-z))

def crossentropy(Y,y):
    return -(Y*np.log(y)+(1-Y)*np.log(1-y))

path = 'D:/DS&ML/ML/data.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(path)
data = np.asarray(data)
x = data[:,0:3]
Y = data [:,3:]
x = np.c_[x, np.ones(len(x))]
m = len(x)
a = 0.015
loss = []
# Layer 1 parameters
t11 = np.random.rand(len(x[1]),1)
t12 = np.random.rand(len(x[1]),1)
# Layer 2 parameters
t21 = np.random.rand(3,1)

for i in range(200):
    # Layer 1 Forward Prop
    z11 = np.matmul(x,t11)
    z12 = np.matmul(x,t12)
    a11 = sigmoid(z11)
    a12 = sigmoid(z12)
    a1 = np.c_[a11,a12,np.ones(m)]

    #Layer 2 Forward Prop
    z21 = np.matmul(a1,t21)
    a21 = sigmoid(z21)

    #Loss Calculation
    J = (1/m)*np.sum(crossentropy(Y,a21))
    loss.append(J)
    
    # Layer 2 Back Prop
    dt21 = (a/m)*np.sum((a21-Y)*a1,axis=0).reshape(3,1)
        
    # Layer 1 Back Prop
    da1 = (np.matmul((a21-Y),a1))[:,0:2]
    da11 = da1[:,0:1]*sigmoid(z11)*(1-sigmoid(z11))
    da12 = da1[:,1:2]*sigmoid(z12)*(1-sigmoid(z12))
    dt11 = (a/m)*np.sum((da11)*x,axis=0).reshape(4,1)
    dt12 = (a/m)*np.sum((da12)*x,axis=0).reshape(4,1)

    # Updating Parameters
    t11 = t11-dt11
    t12 = t12-dt12
    t21 = t21-dt21

plt.plot(loss)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, here are some possible changes you could consider implementing to resolve the problem:

1. Hidden Units: The number of hidden units in Layer 1 is set to 2. It should be `len(x[1]), 2` to match the number of hidden units in the first layer.
2. Bias: Layer 2, you are missing the bias term (t22) when performing forward and backward propagation. Add the bias term to the output of the hidden layer before applying the sigmoid activation function.
3. Cross-Entropy Loss: The cross-entropy loss calculation seems to be incorrect. You should sum the individual losses for each sample before averaging it over all samples.

For better results, consider following changes

1. Learning Rate: You have initialized your learning rate(`a`) too high. It might cause the model to overshoot optimal weights and diverge.
2. Sigmoid Activation Function: In the forward propagation step for Layer 1, you are using the sigmoid activation function for the hidden layer. It might cause the vanishing gradient problem. ReLU (Rectified Linear Unit) is a popular choice for the hidden layer activation as it helps mitigate the vanishing gradient issue.